# Can I have an instance of a parent class in more than one children classes with Joint Table Inheritance?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask and SqlAlchemy. I have an User class, but its members can belong to one or more inheriting classes. Yet,the "type" column just holds one value. How can I make it hold multiple children?

This is the User class:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'    
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, doc='DNI')
    fileNumber: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(db.Integer, nullable=True, doc='Número de legajo')
    first_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(db.String(50), nullable=False, doc='Nombre')
    surname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(db.String(50), nullable=False, doc='Apellido')
    picture = mapped_column(db.LargeBinary, doc='Foto de perfil', nullable=True)
    emails = db.relationship('Email', backref='user', lazy='joined', doc='Emails del usuario')
    phones = db.relationship('Phone', backref='user', lazy='joined', doc='Teléfonos del usuario')
    azure_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=True, doc='ID de Azure AD')
    name = db.column_property(surname + ', ' + first_name)
    type: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(db.String(50), nullable=False, doc='Tipo de usuario')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'user',
        'polymorphic_on': type
    }
```

That has multiple children classes:

```
class DepartmentHead(User, RoleMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'department_head'

    id = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, doc='DNI')
    department_id = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('department.id'), nullable=False, doc='ID del departamento')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'department_head',
        'inherit_condition': id == User.id
    }

class SchoolAdmin(User, RoleMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'school_admin'

    id = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, doc='DNI')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'school_admin',
        'inherit_condition': id == User.id
    }

class SupportStaff(User, RoleMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'support_staff'

    id = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, doc='DNI')
    students = db.relationship('Student', secondary='support_staff_student', backref='support_staff', lazy=True, doc='Alumnos a cargo del personal de apoyo')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'support_staff',
        'inherit_condition': id == User.id
    }

class Student(User, RoleMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'student'

    id = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, doc='DNI')
    grades = db.relationship('Evaluation', backref='student', lazy=True, doc='Notas del / de la estudiante')
    class_id = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('class.id'), nullable=True, doc='Curso')
    year = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('year.id'), nullable=True, doc='Año de cursada')
    cohort = mapped_column(db.Integer, nullable=True, doc='Cohorte')
    responsible_adults = db.relationship('ResponsibleAdult', secondary='responsible_adult_student', backref='students', lazy=True, doc='Adultos responsables del / de la estudiante')
    specialty_id = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('specialty.id'), doc='Orientación')
    canRetire = mapped_column(db.Boolean, nullable=True, doc='Puede retirarse solo/a', default=False)
    graduated = mapped_column(db.Boolean, nullable=True, doc='Graduado/a', default=False)
    state = mapped_column(db.String(50), nullable=True, doc='Estado')
    notes = db.relationship('Note', backref='student', lazy=True, doc='Notas sobre el / la estudiante')
    attendances = db.relationship('Attendance', backref='student', lazy=True, doc='Asistencias del / de la estudiante a la escuela')
    course_attendances = db.relationship('CourseSessionAttendance', backref='students', lazy=True, doc='Asistencias del / de la estudiante a las asignaturas')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'student',
        'inherit_condition': id == User.id
    }

class ResponsibleAdult(User, RoleMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'responsible_adult'

    id = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, doc='DNI')
    postal_address = mapped_column(db.String(100), nullable=False, doc='Dirección postal')
    username = mapped_column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True, doc='Nombre de usuario')
    password_hash = mapped_column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    #students_ids = db.relationship('Student', secondary='responsible_adult_student', backref='responsible_adults', lazy=True, doc='Estudiantes a cargo del adulto responsable')
    isPrimary = mapped_column(db.Boolean, nullable=True, doc='Es el/la adulto/a responsable principal')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'responsible_adult',
        'inherit_condition': id == User.id
    }

class Teacher(User, RoleMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'teacher'

    id = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, doc='DNI')
    departments = db.relationship('Department', secondary=teacher_department, backref='teachers', lazy=True, doc='Departamentos a los que pertenece el / la docente')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'teacher',
        'inherit_condition': id == User.id
    }

class Admin(User, RoleMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'admin'

    id = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, doc='DNI')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'admin',
        'inherit_condition': id == User.id
    }

class ClassTutor(User, RoleMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'class_tutor'
    
    id = mapped_column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, doc='DNI')
    class_id = db.relationship('Class', secondary='class_tutor_class', backref='class_tutors', doc='Cursos a cargo')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'class_tutor',
        'inherit_condition': id == User.id
    }
```

Users can belong to more than one of those classes at the same time. In my own case, I'm an Admin, a Teacher and a CourseTutor.

I didn't get how inheritance worked, until I saw that creating an instance in the "Teacher" class should populate user.type with "teacher". Yet that means that I can't be a Teacher, an Admin and a CourseTutor at the same time.

Am I misunderstanding everything? Is Joined Table Inheritance not the way to go? Is there a way to have more than one type in user.type?

Comment: Personally, I would model this as a many to many relationship between users and roles. So a `User` represents a single person, and that person can have multiple roles.